# Invoking Eclipse plugin from Java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

I have to develop an Engineering tool for my organization, whereby the task is to call the Eclipse plugin like findbug, PMD from the Java Application. Actually this a part of POC that i need to develop. 
Can anyone let me know or have anyone tried to call/invoke the plugin from the Java code ?

Please let me now if anyone has a way or tried that.

Thanks. in advance.

Comment: What you mean "from the java code"? from the build process? from another eclipse plugin?

Comment: Hi Simone,from "Java code" means i need to invoke it from the standalone java application. This is just a part of POC. Actually tools has something more to offer than these.

Comment: You cannot call most Eclipse plugins from a normal Java application because they rely on the Eclipse/OSGi plugin infrastructure created during Eclipse startup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg.Let me tell you the overall scope of the tool. What i want to do is, when the user save the file for eg: .java file, i need to invoke these plugin (findbug, PMD etc) so that code quality checks are performed and the user get warned about the possible quality issues. Is there a way to achieve these?

Comment: @Nayan are you trying to create a new plugin for your POC? Are you trying to change functionality of existing plugin(firebug, PMD) as a POC?

Comment: Hi Kensen, Thanks for the reply. No i am not trying to change the existing functionality of plugin (firebug, PMD). Yes i am creating a new POC for the requirement in my above comment.

Comment: If you want to use Eclipse plugins like this you need to write an Eclipse Rich Client Program (RCP).

Comment: Hi Greg, Thanks for the reply. Can you please give more pointers on Eclipse Rich Client Program (RCP) and how to use it ?

Comment: For example, [SpotBugs, the successor of FindBugs, can also be called as Ant task](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ant.html). This should also allow calling it from a standalone Java application. But why do you need that? For the mentioned validation tools there are Eclipse plugins showing error markers on save and they can also be run in a (Maven) build. So what are you missing? Are you aware of [SonarLint](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint)?

Comment: @daniel-darabos Most Eclipse code is separated in non-Eclipse-specific and Eclipse-specific plugins (mostly with the extension `.ui`) for that purpose. There are even separate projects of non-Eclipse-specific vs. Eclipse-specific Eclipse projects, for instance JGit/EGit or LSP4J/LSP4E. `Platform.getBundle(x)` is Eclipse-specific. Turning an application into an Eclipse-based application should be problem either.